# Using V.net.connect on QGIS 2.18.13

Tags: qgis-processing

I'm trying to use the grass algorithm v.net.connect via the processing menu using a test set of 3 point objects and a single line object. All 4 objects only have geometry and an ID field.
With the parameters set to these two layers and the threshold still at 50.00 and the Network set to save to a temporary file, the algorithm appears to run but does not produce an output.
The log file appears ok bar a line near the end saying "ERROR: option : exists. to overwrite, use the --overwite flag"

My question is how do I set this flag to enable the output? or is this a bug with 2.18.13 as i have used this algorithm in the past on 2.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem. I've updated my QGIS install to version 2.18.15 and the v.net.connect function now works.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar errors with v.net.connect not producing an output in QGIS 2.18 too, and what typically works for me is running [Multipart to singlepart](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/multiparttosingleparts.html) on *both* inputs (line and point layers), prior to running v.net.connect.

In the graphical modeler, it will look something like this:

[image]

You might also have to run v.net.clean on the multipart to singlepart output, but generally that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this solution but still get the same result - no output with an Error indicating an overwrite flag needs to be set. I also tried cleaning the resultant data sets but again, got the same results.

Comment: Perhaps try clearing the temp directory that QGIS uses? On Windows, that is: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp